# When scrolling downwards on a div another div scrolls upwards

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Is it possible to have one dive scroll one direction and at the same time have another div next to it scrolling in the opposite direction using jquery?

Comment: As I understand, you want to do parallax effect. Yes, it is possible. There are many jQuery plugins in the Internet. One of them - http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this,

**Demo:-**
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/

**Source:-** http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Its a perfect example of your requirement...

Thanks..